# Subtract two dates from different columns based on data availability

Tags: python, dataframe

Below is my data-frame.

[image]

I need to subtract dates c/d from a/b based on date availability if 'a' is NA I need to select the value from 'b' and same goes for c and d. If 'c' is NA I need to select the value from 'd'. I need a column 'e' containing the difference.

How to loop through each row and perform this kind of subtraction?

Comment: To be sure, what you want is to take the difference of a and c, but if a or c is NA, you want to swap to use b and/or d accordingly. Correct? If so, you can make intermediate columns for the a or b and c or d, and then just subtract *those* two columns instead. Could you paste the data so that we can try this example out ourselves with your data?

Comment: Yes, what you told is correct, in fact i am struggling to get that intermediate columns. I have code to subtract the date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the logic in my comment, the easiest thing to do with Pandas most of the time is to create intermediate columns. Eventually you can remove them or optimize them away if you don't want them. But it is an easy way to encapsulate your logic. What you want to do is take a dataframe like this:

```
>>> df
          a         b         c         d
0  0.414762  0.113796  0.134529       NaN
1       NaN  0.662192  0.703417       NaN
2  0.958970       NaN  0.237540       NaN
3  0.975512  0.241572       NaN  0.720148
4  0.719265  0.735744  0.801279       NaN
```

and make some intermediate columns that have the value of `df['a']` when it is not `NaN`, and otherwise fill with the value of `df['b']`. You can do this with [`df.fillna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) pretty easily; you can use it to fill the `NaN` values with values from another column. Then you can just take the difference of those two columns. For e.g.:

```
>>> df['a_or_b'] = df['a'].fillna(df['b'])
>>> df['c_or_d'] = df['c'].fillna(df['d'])
>>> df['e'] = df['a_or_b'] - df['c_or_d']
>>> df
          a         b         c         d    a_or_b    c_or_d         e
0  0.414762  0.113796  0.134529       NaN  0.414762  0.134529  0.280233
1       NaN  0.662192  0.703417       NaN  0.662192  0.703417 -0.041225
2  0.958970       NaN  0.237540       NaN  0.958970  0.237540  0.721430
3  0.975512  0.241572       NaN  0.720148  0.975512  0.720148  0.255364
4  0.719265  0.735744  0.801279       NaN  0.719265  0.801279 -0.082013
```

---

This is assuming the missing values are `NaN` but yours are `N/A`. You can also use [`df.replace()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) in the same way to replace the value of strings:

```
>>> df
          a         b         c         d
0  0.414762  0.113796  0.134529       N/A
1       N/A  0.662192  0.703417       N/A
2   0.95897       N/A   0.23754       N/A
3  0.975512  0.241572       N/A  0.720148
4  0.719265  0.735744  0.801279       N/A
>>> df['a_or_b'] = df['a'].replace('N/A', df['b'])
>>> df['c_or_d'] = df['c'].replace('N/A', df['d'])
>>> df['e'] = df['a_or_b'] - df['c_or_d']
>>> df
          a         b         c         d    a_or_b    c_or_d         e
0  0.414762  0.113796  0.134529       N/A  0.414762  0.134529  0.280233
1       N/A  0.662192  0.703417       N/A  0.662192  0.703417 -0.041225
2   0.95897       N/A   0.23754       N/A  0.958970  0.237540  0.721430
3  0.975512  0.241572       N/A  0.720148  0.975512  0.720148  0.255364
4  0.719265  0.735744  0.801279       N/A  0.719265  0.801279 -0.082013
```

Although I do recommend not using strings but actual null-type values when you're working with them, like `NaN` (`np.nan`) or `None` instead of a string like `N/A`.

---

Either way, now you know what the intermediate columns are---so you can just directly use those results instead of actually assigning them to the dataframe if you don't want to.

```
>>> df
          a         b         c         d
0  0.414762  0.113796  0.134529       N/A
1       N/A  0.662192  0.703417       N/A
2   0.95897       N/A   0.23754       N/A
3  0.975512  0.241572       N/A  0.720148
4  0.719265  0.735744  0.801279       N/A
>>> df['e'] = df['a'].replace('N/A', df['b']) - df['c'].replace('N/A', df['d'])
>>> df
          a         b         c         d         e
0  0.414762  0.113796  0.134529       N/A  0.280233
1       N/A  0.662192  0.703417       N/A -0.041225
2   0.95897       N/A   0.23754       N/A  0.721430
3  0.975512  0.241572       N/A  0.720148  0.255364
4  0.719265  0.735744  0.801279       N/A -0.082013
```